# find the particular solution for the equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need help with this calculus problem.  I dont know how to go about starting or finishing this problem

Find the particular solution of the given differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=−3\bigg(\frac{x^2}{y^2}\bigg)$$
where: $y=5$ when $x=1$.

Can anyone try to walk me through this problem please

Answer (score 1):

$$y'(x)=-3\left(\frac{x}{y(x)}\right)^2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y'(x)=-\frac{3x^2}{y(x)^2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y'(x)y(x)^2=-3x^2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int y'(x)y(x)^2\space\text{d}x=\int-3x^2\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

For the integral on the LHS:

Substitute $u=y(x)$ and $\text{d}u=y'(x)\space\text{d}x$.

---

$$\frac{y(x)^3}{3}=\text{C}-x^3$$

Now, to solve $\text{C}$, use $y(1)=5$ (the only solution that fit, will be the real solution):

$$\frac{y(x)^3}{3}=\text{C}-x^3\Longleftrightarrow y(x)=\sqrt[3]{\text{C}-3x^3}$$

Now, use $y(1)=5$:

$$5=\sqrt[3]{\text{C}-3\cdot1^3}\Longleftrightarrow\text{C}=128$$

So:

$$y(x)=\sqrt[3]{128-3x^3}$$

Comment: so what would the answer be in terms of y=

Comment: @google you can solve that by yourself, because it depends on if you also want complex solutions or not.

Comment: i got y=(128/x^3)-3 but is says that not right

Comment: @google See my edit

Answer (score 0):

$$y'=-3\frac{x^2}{y^2}\iff y'y^2=-3x^2$$

Integrate both sides :
$$\frac{y^3}{3}=-x^3+C\iff y^3=-3x^3+3C \iff y=\sqrt[3]{-3x^3+3C}$$

Evaluate $C$ by using that $$y(1)=5\iff \sqrt[3]{-3+3C}=5 \iff-3+3C=125 \iff C=\frac{128}{3}$$
Finally : $y=\sqrt[3]{-3x^3+128}$